# Is it a creditable approach to use Random Forrest Variable importance for causal inference?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, inference, causality, importance

I recently ran into a discussion with a college who used Random Forrest Variable importance to discover causal links between some actions of web users and their characteristics. As I come from econometrics, I was wondering whether this is a good approach, since I intuitively would have fitted a Logistic Regression (the action is binary) and analyze its coefficients for this task. To make it more concrete consider the following problem setting:

Lets say we have a data set $D = (X,y)$ which consists of an output variable $y$ and $d$ explanatory Variables $X = (X_1, \dots, X_d)$. Furthermore, the goal is **not to predict new data points $y$, but only to find causal links between $X$ and $y$**.

Would it be good idea to fit a Random Forrest to the data and extract Variable importance in this setting?

If yes, what are pros and cons of this comparing it to Linear/Logistic Regression coefficient analysis?

Comment: Wait, how can you extract causality from logistic regression coefficients?  Are you assuming the context of a controlled experiment with controls and treatments?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but FYI [David Jensen](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~jensen/) has done a lot of work on inferring actual causal relationships with random forest-type models (scroll down to the "causal modeling" section).

Comment: @MatthewDrury: It is not a controlled experiment. The assumption is that we simply observe data points and than fit a model to find some links between $X$ and $y$. Since the output in this case was binary, I suggested using a Logistic Regression. I would then analyze the coefficients of the model e.g. performing significance tests etc.

Comment: The only way to infer causality is to intervene and see what changes.  You can only infer causality from a regression if you have some prior reason, outside of the regression, to believe the link between the feature and the target is causal.  The regressions only job is to estimate the strength of the effect, not the existence of causality.  This is true for *all* predictive models using observational data.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: You are right that "causality" in a strict scientific sense can not be achieved. From a practical point of view, I look at "the strength of the effect" of some variables $X$ on $y$ to get an idea what might cause $y$.

Comment: Magnitude and sign of an effect from an observational model tells you nothing about the actual causal effect (without very strong assumptions). This also holds for absence of an effect.

Comment: Yes.  You can have just as strong associational effects as causal effects.  I don't see how that practice can be philosophically sound.  Is the intent to follow up with interventions on the effects with a sufficient magnitude to be interesting?

Comment: @MatthewDrury: This is indeed the intention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The analogous concept to parameter estimates in the context of tree based models are *not* the variable importances, they are the **partial dependency plots**.

Recall the a parameter estimate in a regression can be interpreted as the effect of on the predictions of varying a feature, when all other features are held constant.

In a regression (without basis expansions or interactions) the effect of this change is linear with respect to the change in the feature (or linear on the link scale for a glm), and so it can be summarized by a single number.  In a more complex model, this effect is no longer linear, it is instead a curve.  These curves can be plotted, and the result is called a **partial dependence plot**.

So, for example, if you make partial dependence plots from a fit linear regression model (with no basis expansions or interactions) the resulting curves are lines whose slopes are the parameter estimates.

[Here's](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/partial-dependence-plots) a quick overview of the idea, with some code to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to extract causal interpretations from an RF model but certain requirements will need to be met by the model for the extraction to be valid. Similar requirements are also necessary before extracting causal inferences from a simple linear model. The issues around doing so are discussed in [Zhao & Hastie (2017), "Causal Interpretations of Black Box Models"](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/pdp_zhao.pdf).
Beginning of paper's conclusion, "*In contrast to the conventional view that machine learning algorithms are just blackbox predictive models, we have argued that it is possible to extract causal information from these models using the partial dependence plots (PDP) and the individual conditional expectation (ICE) plots. In summary, a successful attempt of causal interpretation requires: (1) A good predictive model, so the black-box function g is (hopefully) close to the law of nature f. (2) Some domain knowledge about the causal structure to assure the back-door condition is satisfied.(3) Visualization tools such as the PDP and its extension ICE.*"